# Didn't get the post thumnail image url of a wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

I am using the function

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
```

But it gives the large image url of the post not the thumb nail image url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your syntax is wrong. Use this to get the url of the featured image:

```
$feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
```

Find a reference [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) and [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url)

Comment: I used the above code but i didn't get the url but it returns the url of large image

Answer (score 2):

If you want the thumbnail, use this function:

```
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
```

wp_get_attachment_image_src returns an array or false if not found.
The array looks like this:

```
 [0] => URL
 [1] => width
 [2] => height
```

`$thumb[0]` is the URL of your thumbnail

Find the reference [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/)